# Issues with toggle, hide and show (Jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, show-hide, popupwindow

I've been looking all over for a script that will take care of the following issues:

http://jsfiddle.net/k7E9V/3/

1. Close the div when clicking outside of it.
2. Close one div when the other one is clicked.
3. Close the div when "More info" is clicked again.

I'm wondering why the minus icon won't stay put when the div is active and also how to restore the plus icon in all the above scenarios.

Comment: There's a "TidyUp" button in the jsfiddle, it helps people reading it. `:P`

Comment: I just don't understand what all the `mouse_inside_div` is for, you only want to open/close/toggle when clicking in the buttons right?

Comment: Oh...`a.active` isn't going to work like that. Make active a class subclass of trigger (`a.trigger.active`)

Comment: I'll be away for the next 10 hours or so, but I finished my answer. Check if it's of use when you can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Final version:  [***jsFiddle***](http://jsfiddle.net/ult_combo/k7E9V/11/)

I made the `:active` selector a subclass of `.trigger` as @Christopher commented and fixed the behavior of the `.trigger` X button to toggle the class accordingly:

```
$('.trigger').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var panel = $(this).next('.panel');
    $('.panel').not(panel).hide();
    panel.toggle("fast");
    $('.trigger').not(this).removeClass('active'); //remove active class from other X buttons
    $(this).toggleClass('active'); //toggle the clicked button's active class
});
```

This way it will remove the `active` class from the other X buttons, and toggle the current one as requested.

To close the boxes when you click outside the `.panel` and `.trigger`, add this inside of your DOM Ready handler:

```
$(document).click('click', function(e) {
    if (!$('.panel').is(':visible')) return;
    var targ = $(e.target);
    //doesn't close the boxes if target is .panel/.trigger or their descendant
    if (targ.closest('.panel').length || targ.is('.panel')
       || targ.closest('.trigger').length || targ.is('.trigger')) return;
    $('.panel').hide('fast');
    $('.trigger').removeClass('active');
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your support, saved me a lot of headache :)

Comment: Hi again, I can't seem to get the code from your Fiddle to work when I put it back in the website code. I probably missed something but i can't figure out what it is.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, could you link the page? It's possible that when copying from jsfiddle it brings some zero-width spaces which break your JS. Or did you fix that already?

Comment: I've rewritten the JS to make sure not zero-width occurs. But it still doesn't work. I used the code from the JSfiddle and added one box (it doesn't work with two boxes either) :/

http://test.gaius.nu/massan.php

Comment: @user1658154 I get an `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL` on Chrome, give me a minute while I review what it could be.

Comment: @user1658154 Found it, there's a `});â€‹` in your `.js` file (after the closing `.trigger` handler), might be an issue with your editor. Try saving your files with UTF-8 encoding and re-upping it, or open it with notepad. `=]`

Comment: @user1658154 I edited the fiddle to add some optimizations, and if you don't manage to remove the invalid characters, here's a [fixed .js](http://temp-share.com/show/3YgFbvuJx).

Comment: I can't thank you enough. It works perfectly now. Must have had something to do with JSfiddle. I appreciate your time and effort :)

Answer (score 3):

The functionality of `:active` is different than what you have in mind. To be able to toggle the icon, first add a CSS rule like this, instead of the `:active` one:

```
a.trigger.isshown{
    background:#fff url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-basic/24/Close-icon.png) 95% 65% no-repeat;
}
```

Now, you can use `.toggleClass('isshown');`, `.removeClass('isshown');` and `.addClass('isshown');` the same way you're toggling/hiding/showing `div` panels to change the icon as well.

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/dwZnG/
Try this out for size.

```
a.trigger{
position: absolute;
text-decoration: none;
bottom:0; 
right: 0;
font-size: 17px;
letter-spacing:-1px;
font-family: verdana, helvetica, arial, sans-serif;
color:#333;
padding: 20px 30px 10px 15px;
font-weight: 600;
background:#fff url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-basic/24/Add-icon.png) 95% 65% no-repeat;
display: block;
}

/* Change active to a class name*/
a.trigger.active {
background:#fff url(http://icons.iconarchive.com/icons/deleket/sleek-xp-basic/24/Close-icon.png) 95% 65% no-repeat;
}
```

Then your JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.trigger').click(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var me = $(this);
        var panel = me.next('.panel');
        //If active is there, remove it
        if (me.hasClass("active")) {
            me.removeClass("active");
        }
        //If it ain't...add it
        else {
            me.addClass("active");
        }
        $('.panel').not(panel).hide();
        panel.toggle("fast");
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.panel').hover(function() {
                mouse_inside_div = true;
            }, function() {
                mouse_inside_div = false;
            });
            $('body').mouseup(function() {
                if (!mouse_inside_div) $('.panel').hide();

            });
        });
        });
    });​
```

Basically the same thing as Abody said. Once you have this down, you should be able to figure out the rest of the functionality.

Comment: Thank you for your help Christopher :)